# Select and check if nth column from recordset is empty in access vba

Tags: vba, count, ms-access-2010, recordset

I have recordset in Access from table with 25 columns. I need to write a makro where program select column 10, checks if it is empty or not, and then do the same check for every 3rd column till the end of the recordset

I wrote below makro, I tried to count number of columns in recordset and then set variable from 10th column to the end of the recordset as below

```
Public Sub calculations()
Dim Tactical  As dao.Database
Dim rsvol As dao.Recordset
Dim i As Long

Set Tactical = CurrentDb
Set rsvol = Tactical.OpenRecordset("Calculations Table")

Debug.Print rsvol.Fields.Count
For i = 10 To rsvol.Fields.Count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the empty fields after field 10 that are null.
It assumes you only have a single field set as the Primary Key.  If you've got more than one field set as PK then you'll need to split the `PrimKey` variable.

On a side note it looks like you're trying to use a database table the same way you would a spreadsheet.  They're not really comparable.

Some SQL like below would return records where certain fields are null.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
WHERE   Field10 Is Null OR Field12 Is Null or Field15 Is Null Or Field18 Is Null
```

This code will search through the table and print in the immediate window which fields are null and what the PK value is for that record.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim Tactical As DAO.Database
    Dim rsVol As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set Tactical = CurrentDb
    Set rsVol = Tactical.OpenRecordset("Table1")
    
    Dim x As Long
    With rsVol
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        
            Dim PrimKey As String
            PrimKey = GetPrimaryKey(rsVol.Name)
        
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .BOF And Not .EOF
                For x = 10 To .Fields.Count
                    If IsNull(.Fields(x - 1)) Then
                        Debug.Print "PK: " & .Fields(PrimKey) & " - " & .Fields(x - 1).Name & " is empty"
                    End If
                Next x
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetPrimaryKey(TableName As String) As String

    With CurrentDb
        Dim td As DAO.TableDef
        Set td = .TableDefs(TableName)
        
        Dim idxLoop As Index
        For Each idxLoop In td.Indexes
            If idxLoop.Primary Then
                GetPrimaryKey = Mid(idxLoop.Fields, 2)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next idxLoop
    End With

End Function
```